# SQLiteDatabase isReadOnly method raises exception (almost always)

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

In the following code I get an exception 'database is not open' at the line 'isReadOnly'. It's definitely open as you can see by the logic. In fact almost everywhere in my code where I try to do a isReadOnly check I get an exception. Is there something obvious I'm missing or is there a bug in this method (I'm on gingerbread).

As far as I can see it's almost a simple conditional statement with a lock on mLock so I can't see how it can be causing an exception here.

Also, if I have a readable database will calling getWritableDatabase() always be ok and there's no need for closing first?

```
if (!db.isOpen()) {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
} else {
    if (db.isReadOnly()) {
        db.close();
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Damn! after months of trying to figure it out, I realise what was happening shortly after posting this question.

isReadOnly was just a red-herring, though why it gravitated there I don't know.

Essentially, in debug mode I noticed that my app was calling onPause and in my onpause I was closing the database.

I wonder if there's a way to stop android from calling onpause when you're half way through debugging.....